# code and xml in setcontentview android

Tags: android, user-interface

I've set my `setContentView` to a view (code) but now I need an xml to add a button on it. Is it possible to combine UI with code and xml? If it's possible than what should I do and add in my code?

Here's the code:

```
public class Diagram extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

grafik mgrafik;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mgrafik = new grafik(this);

        setContentView( mgrafik);  
    }  
}
```

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alhamdulillah, Finally i could combine the button and the grafik, using relativelayout  by coding. Here's the source.

```
public class Diagram extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
grafik mgrafik;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout (this);
    rel.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    mgrafik = new grafik(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams grf = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    grf.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("Kembali");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pbtn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pbtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);


    rel.addView(mgrafik, grf);
    rel.addView(btn, pbtn);

    setContentView(rel); 

}
```

}

Thank's all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `grafik` is some kind of `View` you may just put it into your xml: `<com.whatever.grafik.../>`

Comment: I've tried it on absoluteLayout it has no error. But when I run the program on android simulator it said that the activity stop unexpectedly and need to be closed. any other idea?

Comment: Probably because you didn't add a second constructor. What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: How should i put the second constructor? And what is stacktrace? is it this[2011-08-16 08:05:43 - CobaPass] Installing CobaPass.apk...
[2011-08-16 08:06:25 - CobaPass] Success!
[2011-08-16 08:06:25 - CobaPass] Starting activity coba.pass.CobaPassActivity on device emulator-5554
[2011-08-16 08:06:27 - CobaPass] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=coba.pass/.CobaPassActivity }

Comment: A stacktrace tells you exactly what went wrong. When using a View in xml you always need to provide this constructor: public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

Comment: where should i put that constructor on grafik.java or on Diagram.java? and what should i write inside that constructor? i'm sorry to bother you i'm a newbie. thanks

Comment: You put it in the class you put in your xml and in contains the same stuff as your normal constructor... maybe nothing. Android reads the xml, sees you use grafik in there and needs to be able to call new grafik(...)

Comment: I set this setContentView(R.layout.gambar); on Diagram.java . So i should put the constructor there?